# Pegar coluna específica csv com python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tenho um método que abre um arquivo CSV porém gostaria de ir direto em uma coluna específica, tentei fazer dessa forma `list2 = [row.split()[3] for row in f]`, porém retorna um pedaço do arquivo e não a coluna. É possível fazer isso sem usar o PANDAS?
Meu método:

```
import csv
list2 = []
count = 0

with open('meuarquivo.csv') as f:
    list2 = [row.split()[3] for row in f]

while(count <= 20):
    print(list2[count])
    count+=1
```

Comment: As colunas estão separadas por vírgula? Se sim, usa o `row.split(',')`. `split` sem parâmetros separa por espaços.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, é possível fazer leitura de uma coluna especifica sem utilizar bibliotecas externas como o [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/), o seu código não funciona pois você não especificou qual é o separador das colunas no `split`. Criei uma variável para o separador caso você esteja usando outro, basta mudar.

```
''' Conteudo CSV
nome,idade
Laerte,23
Maria,18
'''

separador = ','

with open('teste.csv', 'r') as txt_file:
    for line_number, content in enumerate(txt_file):
        if line_number:  # pula cabeçalho
            colunas = content.strip().split(separador)
            print(f"Nome: {colunas[0]}, \nIdade: {colunas[1]}")
```

O if é para verificar se não é linha do cabeçalho e sim linha contendo os dados.

Answer (score 1):

Basta você utilizar o próprio módulo `csv` que importou no seu exemplo, utilizando a classe [`DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader), por exemplo:

```
def get_column_of_csv(filename, column):
  with open(filename) as stream:
    reader = csv.DictReader(stream)
    for row in reader:
      yield row[column]
```

Assim, para um CSV:

```
seq,firstname,lastname,age
1,Helen,King,58
2,Emilie,Joseph,59
3,Bess,Frazier,29
4,Amy,Gross,33
5,Olga,Sutton,62
6,Gary,Moreno,54
7,Myrtie,Freeman,47
8,Philip,Adkins,32
9,Thomas,Morales,64
10,Stella,Rodgers,43
```

Poderíamos fazer

```
for name in get_column_of_csv('data.csv', 'firstname'):
  print(name)
```

Obtendo o resultado

```
Helen
Emilie
Bess
Amy
Olga
Gary
Myrtie
Philip
Thomas
Stella
```

Vale comentar que, por padrão, a classe `DictReader` irá considerar a primeira linha do arquivo CSV como sendo o nome das colunas, por isso foi possível identificar a coluna `firstname` no código.